# Change code for different extraction criteria

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am using a prototype tool and I want to extract from a written text whatever is between commas. In order to do it I use this code 
`(/,([^)]+),/).exec("{email_content}")[1]`  and it works really well.

Does anyone know how do I change it in order to extract the text which is among a `,` and a `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the last comma in your regex with `\?` (a literal question mark), but this will match the question mark too.

You can also use lookaheads in JS if you don't want the regex to consume the question mark: `(?=\?)`.

Also, you can simplify your base regex like that: `/,(.+?),/` (using a non-greedy quantifier)
So the answer to your question would be: `/,(.+?)(?=\?)/`

Comment: thanks It worked. Do you also know how can I modify it in order to take all the text between the , and the ? becuse as it is it takes only if they are in the same line, otherwise it does not work..

Comment: Sure, just add the `s` modifier like this: `/,(.+?)(?=\?)/s`. This modifier allows `.` to match newlines.